# Crop image into a small rect programmatically

Tags: iphone, imageview, crop, pinch

I want to crop an image 300*300. I want to crop the face from that image.

I think we can use a doted rectangle and then move and scale according to the area we want.

Comment: have you got the correct answer from the following? if Yes then accept that one.

Comment: A link-only answer below recommends [this resource](http://maniacdev.com/2011/10/open-source-library-to-add-image-cropping-into-an-ios-app-quickly/). I am preserving it here in case that is deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([largeImage CGImage], cropRect);

[UIImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]]; 

CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```